# Python subprocess get output as process finishes

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, popen

Currently I am getting MAC addresses from devices via Bluetooth and I pass these mac addresses one at a time to a method that calls a subprocess and assigns the output to a variable.  With that variable I run some filtering functions to get a value from the command called in the subprocess. I then return that value if it finds it from the output.

What I would like to do is pass all mac addresses to the method at once and run them all at one time. How do I capture the output of each process and run my filtering script as the processes complete, and at the same time notify me if the process fails or errors.

Here is the current method that handles one mac at a time. Lets assume now that I am passing a list of mac addresses.

```
 def getchan(mac):
  a = subprocess.Popen(["sdptool", "search","--bdaddr", mac, "OPUSH"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()[2:]
  if a==[]:
      print "ERROR"
      return "ERROR"
  else:
      count = 0
      for item in a:
          if item == "Channel:":
              return a[count + 1]
          count += 1
      return "Could not find the OPUSH channel"
```

It should look something like

```
def getchan(macs):
processes = set()
for mac in macs:
  processes.add(subprocess.Popen(["sdptool", "search","--bdaddr", mac, "OPUSH"], stdout =      subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split()[2:])
  #this is where I need the help
```

Thank you for taking a look. Any help or clarification of Subprocesses would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
import select
import subprocess

def in_parallel(processes):
    pipes = {p.stdout.fileno(): (i, p.stdout) for i, p in enumerate(processes)}

    poller = select.poll()
    for fd, pipe in pipes.iteritems():
        poller.register(fd, select.POLLIN)

    outputs = [''] * len(processes)

    while pipes:
        active = poller.poll()
        for fd, event in active:
            idx, pipe = pipes[fd]
            o = pipe.read()
            if o:
                outputs[idx] += o
            else:
                poller.unregister(fd)
                pipe.close()
                del pipes[fd]

    for p in processes:
        p.wait()

    return outputs

args = ['a', 'b', 'c']
processes = [subprocess.Popen(['sleep 5; echo ' + arg], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) for arg in args]
outputs = in_parallel(processes)
print outputs
```

---

```
$ time python test.py
['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n']

real    0m5.042s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.016s
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get output from subprocesses in parallel in a portable manner is to use threads:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads
from subprocess import check_output

def getchan_mp(mac):
    try:
        output = check_output(["sdptool", "search","--bdaddr", mac, "OPUSH"])
        result = parse(output)
        return result, mac, None
    except Exception as err:
        return None, mac, err

results = Pool(processes=len(macs)).map(getchan_mp, macs)
failed_macs = [mac for result, mac, error in results if error is not None]
```